# os.access(os.getcwd(), os.W_OK|os.X_OK) but Permission denied

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm writing a csv file with ipynb into a folder with

`pd.DataFrame(data.Event.unique()).to_csv(os.getcwd())`

I've check my write access with

```
os.access(os.getcwd(), os.W_OK|os.X_OK)
```

which return `True` and
tried runing Jupyter as administration
However I stil get an error.

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuclV.jpg)

Here's the stack trace

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-7489dfffa317> in <module>
----> 1 pd.DataFrame(data.Event.unique()).to_csv(os.getcwd())

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, tupleize_cols, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal)
   1743                                  doublequote=doublequote,
   1744                                  escapechar=escapechar, decimal=decimal)
-> 1745         formatter.save()
   1746 
   1747         if path_or_buf is None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py in save(self)
    154             f, handles = _get_handle(self.path_or_buf, self.mode,
    155                                      encoding=encoding,
--> 156                                      compression=self.compression)
    157             close = True
    158 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in _get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text)
    398         elif encoding:
    399             # Python 3 and encoding
--> 400             f = open(path_or_buf, mode, encoding=encoding)
    401         elif is_text:
    402             # Python 3 and no explicit encoding

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\ecom\\Product\\POD\\New folder\\News'
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with pandas. Run your script as an admin.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to save the csv file using the exact same name as the directory itself, i.e. `...\New Folder\News`, not `...\New Folder\News\myfile.csv`.

Comment: Thanks it seems like that fix it.